# extract string by multiple conditions in for loop python pandas

Tags: string, pandas, loops

I would like to extract pandas string with multiple conditions by applying if else in a loop. However, it seems not work and only return first column already. Any advices for that?

```
|col_a|col_b|
|peter--bob:5067561|peter--bob:5067561|
|chris**bbb:5067561|chris**bbb:5067561|
|bob##ccc:5067561|bob##ccc:5067561|


def get_string(df):

    cols = df.columns[0:20]

    for col in cols:

        if col.find('*') == -1: 
            return df[col].astype(str).str.split('*').str[0]

        if col.find('-') == -1:
            return df[col].astype(str).str.split('-').str[0]

        if col.find('#') == -1:
            return df[col].astype(str).str.split('#').str[0]
```

Comment: Can you ad some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Take a quick look on python basics on functions first ! When you return a value, the function is not executed anymore (except in some very specific cases), so it'll never get to the second iteration of the for loops! ;]

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop is tested column name instead column values. Solution is select column by `df[col]` and test by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), apply solution and assign back to `DataFrame`:

```
def get_string(df):

    cols = df.columns[0:20]

    for col in cols:
        for v in ['*','-','#']:
            mask = df[col].str.contains(v, na=False, regex=False)
            df.loc[mask, col] = df.loc[mask, col].str.split(v).str[0]

    return df

print (get_string(df))
   col_a  col_b
0  peter  peter
1  chris  chris
2    bob    bob
```

Comment: basically, I like to apply to column's value not for column name

Comment: @ChrisChang - Answer was edited, but not sure how need output.

Comment: I have edited the data example, could you help to check

Comment: @ChrisChang - Can you check expected output in edited answer?